# displaying an image streamed back from an express server

Tags: html, image, express, binary, blob

Currently attempting to return and display an image from an api, within an img tag.
I'm unsure what data type is being returned, and i'm unsure how to process it to allow it to be shown within the image tag.

The data seems to be returned in the same format whether I use pipe(), or res.sendFile().

Here is the server

```
app.get('/image', (req,res) => {
    var p = path.join(__dirname, './uploads', 'DSC_3985.JPG'); 
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
    fs.createReadStream(p).pipe(res);
})
```

Here is a snippet of the data / file which is returned, when printed to the console.

```
8>����*��5&�`�P���o��U�@�3�7������f��I��CH�6���>���sILB�iv
WwW&�~�N��2�5�\����{��j�����^�z��yl�,��=)�&�6��y�5�XM��o�psB�e�
fTe�׊��$gz�n�6Rۣ�/$n��QY2���߭C�DV#i_�'<�����N�����
```

I've tried the following

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxx...">
```

I've also attempted to treat the data as a blob 
I've also attempted to read the data as  a file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the storage of the image, not the retrieval.

I was storing the image on the server using the npm package multer, and not specifying the mimetype in the storage function.

This caused the file to be uploaded without a mimetype.

Adding the required mimetype to the uploaded file resolved my issue.